# Qt: how do I make a field of 2d-interpolated colors?

Tags: c++, qt, colors, 2d, interpolation

I'm quite a beginner with c++, especially graphically related.
I would like to make an animated background for my graphicsview which looks kind of like this:

[Gradient Field Airflow](http://www.engineering.leeds.ac.uk/cfd/research/images/untitled.JPG)

The picture represents the turbulence of an airflow over an object.
The colors must be based on a matrix of values.

I can only find how to do single-direction gradients with QT.

How do I set this up? How do I get two-directional gradients?

/*edit
It has been pointed out well that technically speaking this is not a gradient, but an color interpolation on a 2d array of nodes.
*/

Comment: What you are describing has nothing to do with "gradients" as meant in graphical frameworks. What you want to do is to interpolate values on a 2d array of nodes.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do, I'll edit my post.
Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on gradients in Qt: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-gradients.html and a class: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qgradient.html I have never used other than linear gradients and according to the docs, it seems there are only three basic types of gradients available in Qt: linear, radial and conical. If you cannot compose your desired gradient using these three types, then I am afraid you will need to program your image pixels by yourself. Not to forget, it might be worthy to explore if OpenGL somehow could help. Qt has some classes using OpenGL but I am not familiar with them to provide more advice.

Comment: Hmm, well these gradients you mentioned are the ones I'm trying to work with already. My question is how to implement them to get the desired result

Comment: OK, it was not clear from your question what options you have already tried. If you need to implement custom gradients I would look at QImage where you can access individual pixels and then you can implement your mathematical algorithm for color interpolation. You can mix the colors yourself (there probably is a googlable algorithm for color mixing) or your can use alpha component of RGBA to create the transition automatically. However I am not sure about the performance of these two approaches. But you can never know until you try.

Comment: Sounds like an idea, do you have an example from which I can start working, since I have no idea where to start (combination of QImage and QGraphicsScene)

Comment: Well, I have always been interested into graphics but never really tried such a low-level task. I would start here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#pixel-manipulation Then you just need some prescription representing your gradient calculation, i.e. mathematical function mapping (x,y) space to (r,g,b) or (r,g,b,a) space. But I am not sure how to combine QImage and QGraphicsScene... Maybe try QBrush::setTextureImage and then use this brush for painting to QGraphicsScene or other way could be convert QImage to QPixmap and then call QGraphicsScene::addPixmap.

Comment: I've solved the problem using OpenGL, which was my second shot. Anyways thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have not provided the input data so no one knows what you really want to achieve !

1. **if you have the flow trajectories and mass**

   Then you can use some particle system + heavy blurring/smoothing filtering to achieve this. For any known point along the trajectory plot a dithered circle with color depend on the mass/temp/velocity... and color scale. It should be solid in the middle and transparent on the edges. After rendering just blur/smooth the image few times and that should be it. The less points used the bigger the circles must be to cover the area nicely also can do it in multi pass and change the points coordinates randomly to improve randomness in the image...
2. **if you have field strength/speed/temp or what ever grid values**

   Then it is similar to **#1** also you can instead of particle system do the rendering via QUADs/Squares. The 2D linear gradient is called **Bilinear Filtering**

   ```
       c00   -- x -->  c01

         |
         |
         y      c(x,y)
         |
         |
         V

       c10              c11
   ```

where:

- `c00,c01,c10,c11` are corner colors
- `c(x,y)`  is color on `x,y` position inside square
- `x,y` are in range `<0,1>` for simplicity (but you can use any with appropriate equations scaling)

**Bilinear interpolation** is **3x linear interpolation**:

```
        c0=c(x,0)=c00+((c01-c00)*x)
        c1=c(x,1)=c10+((c11-c10)*x)
        c(x,y)   =c0 +((c1 -c0 )*y)
```

so render all pixels of the square with above computed colors and that is what you seek. This kind of filtering usually produce artifacts on the edges between squares or on diagonals to avoid that use non linear filtering or blur/smooth the final image