# How to use bilinear interpolation on 2d axis?

Tags: math, interpolation

In my application i find 4 nearest points on the grid $(x1,y1)$, $(x2,y2)$, $(x3,y3)$, $(x4,y4)$ for a signal that detected with unknown location using knn. Each of these points have a specific RSSI reading.$(rss1, rss2, rss3)$. How do i apply Bi-linear interpolation to find the x y coordinates of the grid ?

Comment: see [Bilinear Filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21132906/2521214)  but I get the impresion that your grid points are not orthogonal at all when you have 4 coordinates per axis. add an example values or draw an image. Just to be sure `(xi,yi)` are knonws (grid points) `rssi` are unknowns and `x,y` is the input known point you want  interpolate `rssi` for

Answer (score 0):

Bilinear interpolation solves direct (forward) problem - finds value in the point with given coordinates, it has unique solution. You are trying to solve inverse problem - find coordinates by value.

Note that bilinear equation contains two coordinates, giving single result value. So you cannot get inverse solution for two unknowns using single value.

If you `RSSI reading` is a set of three **independent** values, than you can build a system of two equations with two unknowns and solve it, refining result using the third value. But remember that solution might be ambiguous.

Comment: dear MBo- Actually im using particle filter which estimate x y. So in this process i use the estimated x y in the equation to predict readings with the actual and make the correction to estimate position.